# Display processed values in Jtable column and sort using raw values?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a table in database, the first column of this table contains some numeric values, this is the raw data. There is a specific algorithm to convert these raw numeric values to processed text values.
How can i achieve:

- display the processed text data in Jtable. where should I process the raw numeric values? in resultset? in data model? in jtable?
- sort rows in Jtable using this column but using the original raw numeric values, not the displayed processed text values. is this even possible?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The raw data should be stored in the TableModel. A renderer is used to control what is displayed in the table. For example you store 123456 as an Integer in the TableModel, then the default renderer for Integers will display "123,456" in the table.

So in your case you need to create a custom renderer.

Take a look at [Table Format Renderers](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/). It shows a simple example of how you can override the `setValue(...)` method of the `DefaultTableCellRenderer`.

> I want to sort rows in Jtable using this column but using the original raw numeric values, not the displayed processed text values. is this even possible?

Yes, the table sorter sorts based on the data in the TableModel.